# Sql with strange join order

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I inherited a SQL query with a syntax I'm not familiar with.

It looks something like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TableA AS TableA
     INNER JOIN #TableB AS TableB
     INNER JOIN #TableC AS TableC
         ON TableC.Id1 = TableB.Id1
         ON TableB.Id2 = TableA.Id2
```

and it works (SQL Server 2019).

There are several other unrelated queries using the same syntax so it is definitely intentional.

I first thought it might be that the order of `ON` clauses doesn't matter since they can all be moved to the `WHERE` clause anyway.

But then I tried

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TableA AS TableA
     INNER JOIN #TableB AS TableB
     INNER JOIN #TableC AS TableC
         ON TableC.Id1 = TableB.Id1
            AND TableC.Id3 = TableA.Id3
         ON TableB.Id2 = TableA.Id2
```

And got squiggles with a tool tip

> 'TableA.Id3' could not be bound

Executing it results in an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'Id3'

So can someone explain how this syntax works?

Here is setup code

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TableA (Id1 int, Id2 int, Id3 int);
CREATE TABLE #TableB (Id1 int, Id2 int, Id3 int);
CREATE TABLE #TableC (Id1 int, Id2 int, Id3 int);
```

Comment: Nested joins.. typical for left joins eg A left join B left join C ..but if B and C are dependent then A left join (B join C)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125422/what-does-the-position-of-the-on-clause-actually-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When these are all `INNER JOIN`s this syntax is a little pointless, if I am honest, but I'll cover this off later.

Let's take the first statement you have:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TableA AS TableA
     INNER JOIN #TableB AS TableB
     INNER JOIN #TableC AS TableC
         ON TableC.Id1 = TableB.Id1
         ON TableB.Id2 = TableA.Id2
```

What we have here is a deferred `ON` clause for the `INNER JOIN` to `#TableB`.  The second `ON` clause is actually for the `INNER JOIN` on `#TableB`.

When using this syntax, objects *outside* of the scope of the table the `JOIN` is deferred on *cannot* be referenced. It's not identical syntax (as this uses a derived table), but it might be easier to demonstrate why your second query fails with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TableA AS TableA
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM #TableB AS TableB
                      INNER JOIN #TableC AS TableC ON TableC.Id1 = TableB.Id1
                 WHERE TableB.Id2 = TableA.Id2) BC;
```

This will generate a similar error, as the table aliased as `TableA` cannot be referenced in the derived table.

This syntax, in my opinion, makes more sense when you have a `LEFT JOIN` involved. TAke the following instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TableA TableA
     LEFT JOIN #TableB TableB
                INNER JOIN #TableC TableC ON TableC.Id1 = TableB.Id1
                ON TableB.Id2 = TableA.Id2;
```

So here, for the `LEFT JOIN` to find a related row then there *must* be a related row in `TableC` to `TableB`, if no row from the `INNER JOIN` is found, then `TableB` also won't be joined to. This would not be the same as the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #TableA TableA
     LEFT JOIN #TableB TableB ON TableB.Id2 = TableA.Id2
     INNER JOIN #TableC TableC ON TableC.Id1 = TableB.Id1;
```

Here this would effectively turn the `LEFT JOIN` to `TableB` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`, due to a row *needing* to be found in `TableC`, and the only way a row could be found is it `TableB.Id2` had a non-`NULL` value (which is impossible if no row was found).

Comment: I used inner join in the simplified example but the real one has a mixture of them. Thank you for a very nice explanation. I now understand how it works. Am I correct that it is also pointless if both are left joins?

Comment: Yes, it would be, @adrianm .